# Get the return value from script block

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I created a script following the example in the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs.aspx. However, I need a list of the returned value `$result` of the script block at the end. How to modify the script to accomplish it?

```
$maxConcurrentJobs = 3;

# Read the input and queue it up
$jobInput = get-content .\input.txt
$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized( (New-Object System.Collections.Queue) )
foreach($item in $jobInput)
{
    $queue.Enqueue($item)
}

# Function that pops input off the queue and starts a job with it
function RunJobFromQueue
{
    if( $queue.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
           param($x); 
           #..... 
           $result ######### Need this value returned to the main script
           } -ArgumentList $queue.Dequeue()
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $j -EventName StateChanged -Action { 
           RunJobFromQueue; 
           Unregister-Event $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier; 
           Remove-Job $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier 
           } | Out-Null
    }
}

# Start up to the max number of concurrent jobs
# Each job will take care of running the rest
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $maxConcurrentJobs; $i++ )
{
    RunJobFromQueue
}
######## Process a list of $result
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the $result to a file.

When you get to the '# Process a list of $result' - point, look for files and deserialize them.

**Note**: you will have to find a good way of determining when your asynchronous jobs have completed first! (Maybe use job-name = $result file name, if $result file name = a job-name that doesn't exist, it's safe to open)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Receive-Job $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier` before removing the finished job, and don't pipe the output into `Out-Null`.